# Javascript - How to add strings with quotation marks inside a quotation mark?

Tags: javascript, string, quotation-marks

I'm not sure what's the best way to word this question but basically I'm working on my second Javascript project to build a Random Quote Generator when I noticed there's some syntax issues on my third quote (please see first screenshot) when my strings include words like "don't" or "can't". I'm not sure if it's because I wrote my strings as '"quote" - author' but this person on Youtube (please see second screenshot) wrote his strings using the same format but hadn't had any syntax issue.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct16T.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiRO4.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just add a backslash (escape character) before the `'` character? In the second picture he's using an alternate apostrophe (not `'`) but similar.

Answer (score 4):

All of the above lines are allowed in JavaScript:

```
// delimiter: double quotes
// don't need to escape single quotes
// must escape double quotes
const s1 = "a 'test' a";     
const s2 = "a \"test\" a";

// delimiter: single quotes
// must escape single quotes
// don't need to escape double quotes
const s3 = 'a \'test\' a';
const s4 = 'a "test" a';

// delimiter: grave accent (template literal)
// don't need to escape double quotes
// neither single quotes
const s5 = `a 'test' a`;
const s6 = `a "test" a`;

// string interpolation
const n = 10;
const s7 = `n value is ${n}`;  // evaluates to: n value is 10
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Interesting. In all my years of JavaScript I did not know about the grave accent.

Comment: @JohnSmith it's used for string interpolation and tagged templates. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

Using the Escape Character ()
"Then he said, "Hello, World!""

```
let quote = "Then he said, \"Hello, World!\"";
```

Comment: There is another way and it's backticks. Check that out too.

Comment: I think backticks suit my situation better

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks instead of quotation mark :

```
const str = "hello "people" from Africa" // wrong way

const correctStr = `hello people from "some country name " and "another" ` //coorect way
```